# rapid consumption of ActiveMQ messages

Tags: activemq-classic

i am sending appx 1000 messages/sec in to ActiveMQ queue, via Camel Route. Camel Context is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd 
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


<camelContext id="MsgServlet" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">


     <route id="ConfigComponent">
             <from uri="timer:foo?period=25s"/>
             <to uri="http://10.53.138.245:8080/demo/DemoServlet?component=1"/>


             <to uri="bean:InitConfig?method=process"/>

            </route>


        <route id="servletToProcessor">
            <from uri="jetty:http://10.53.138.100:10666/mytestservice"/>
              <unmarshal>
                <json library="Jackson"/>
            </unmarshal>
            <to uri="bean:MsgProcessor?method=process"/>
             <to uri="activemq:queue:inbox" pattern="InOnly"/>
            </route>

         <route id="inToOutRoute">
          <from uri="activemq:queue:inbox"/>
          <to uri="bean:ESPProcessor?method=process"/>
         </route>



    </camelContext>

    <bean id="InitConfig" class="org.sap.camel.iot.example.InitConfig">
    </bean>


    <bean id="MsgProcessor" class="org.sap.camel.iot.example.MsgProcessor">
    </bean>

      <bean id="ESPProcessor" class="org.sap.camel.iot.example.ESPProcessor">
    </bean>

      <bean id="MMSProcessor" class="org.sap.camel.iot.example.MMSProcessor">
    </bean>

    <broker id="broker" brokerName="myBroker" useShutdownHook="false" useJmx="true"
                   persistent="true" dataDirectory="activemq-data"
                   xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- vm transport for intra-jvm communication -->
            <transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://myBroker"/>
            <!-- tcp for external communication -->
            <transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry queue="inbox"  maxPageSize="1000" memoryLimit="100MB" queuePrefetch="2000"/>
        </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

    </broker>




    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" id="amq">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledCF" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop" id="pooledCF" init-method="start">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="AMQCF" />
  <property name="maxConnections" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" id="AMQCF">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://myBroker?create=false&amp;waitForStart=5000"/>
        <property name="userName" value="karaf"/>
        <property name="password" value="karaf"/>
        <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="true" />
        <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />

        <property name="prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch" value="2000"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

issue i am facing is, its taking lot of time to empty the queue. what configuration changes i need to do to clean up the queue at earliest?

Regards,
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by either increasing the number of concurrentConsumers i.e horizontal or by using the Threading model. The camel documentation suggests that the threading a faster option to concurrentConsumers.

Here's a good discussuion thread that describes this : [Apache Camel concurrentConsumers vs threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985792/apache-camel-concurrentconsumers-vs-threads)